# Why are these two meshes different?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, faces

[image: comparing meshes]

The box on the right is perfect but the box on the left, the edge is kinda glitched how do I fix this?

Comment: First can you please NOT USE ALL CAPS.

Comment: why does it matter? if your not helping just dont comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to join all the faces together, then you can:

- Select all faces you want to join together
- Press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Faces*

Comment: You are welcome :) I was down voted & banned from answering to all questions across blender stackexchange because of that lol.... I am glad you got it to work though ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the image you provided, the difference between the two meshes is that in the one on the left, you subdivided the top and bottom faces before doing the inset, resulting in multiple loop cuts on the sides. Depending upon how you plan to use the box, this may or may not be a problem, but at this point if you want to fix it, the easiest way would be to delete the mesh and start over.